# Can you add a Console program to a WindowsFormApplication program?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a C# WindowsFormApplication project to collect and store answers. 
I then want to use these answers to generate input for selenium web driver which is a console application.

Is it possible to join the two projects together so I first collect my answers on the form, and when I click `run` on the windows application form, for the console application to start running? If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you don't want to use database as suggested by kat0r you can use sockets to make them communicate together.

Comment: I haven't heard of sockets before, would this enable me to launch a console app from within a windows application form and send over relevant data to that console app?

Comment: Sockets is not responsible for opening applications, this can be easily done with the Process class. Once the two applications are open sockets are used for communication between them. It is basically a way for the applications to open ports on the system and send messages through these ports.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer would be to store the questions in a file/database, and simply access it from both applications. You can start other programs with something like [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process)